# Yii2 - Delete record in database not working

Tags: php, yii2

So I am trying to delete a record in a database with a form. But unfortunately the action does nothing. here is the code
Action:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers\backend\calculator;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Action;
use app\models\calculator\CalculatorFunctionsModel;

class DeleteAction extends Action
{
    public function run()
    {
        $model = new CalculatorFunctionsModel;

        if($model->validate())
        {
            $session = Yii::$app->session;

            $session->open();

            $position = Yii::$app->request->post('CalculatorFunctionsModel')['function_position'];

            $function = CalculatorFunctionsModel::find()->where(['function_position' => $position])->one();
            $function->delete();
            
        }
        
        return $this->controller->render('../backend/calculator/delete', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Html;
?>

<h1>Delete a function</h1>

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'options' => [
        'id' => 'DeleteFunctionForm',
    ],
]) ?>

<p>Which position is the function at?</p>

<?= $form->field($model, 'function_position') ?>

<?= Html::submitButton('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'id' => 'DeleteSubmit']) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

I don't get an error or anything. It just does nothing. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You're validating empty model - I would guess that `$model->validate()` returns `false`.

Comment: You're right, I switchet it out for `if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))` Thank you for youre help!